# Kafka - Synchronized Consumer Groups

Tags: apache-kafka

i am trying to make my head regarding Kafka consumers and I'd like to know if the following use case can be solved using Kafka.

My use case is basically this one:

I have a stream that I'd like to be consumed in sync by several consumers. In other words, I have a first consumer that starts to consume the stream, then another consumer arrives later. I'd like this second consumer to start to consume the stream at the offset where is currently the first consumer.

I know that I need to have the consumers in two different groups. But it is not clear for me :

- on how or if it is possible to coordinate the groups offset
- if I would expect a latency for such coordination task

Answer (score 1):

You do not need two different groups, all consumers can check one topic. Or as many as they like, for that matter.

**offset**

Messages typically are identified by their arrival date, so all the clients need to tell the producer "my last visit was at 10:00, give me all new messages". So all each client needs to keep track of is when which individual topic was checked last.

**latency**

this is kind of "of scope" at this point. Of course there will be latency, but it depends on the environment, like "how many consumers", "how many topics", "message format" etc.

**so can your usecase be solved using kafka**

In short: yes. "Can one consumer continue where another has left", the consumers could exchange the latest index between each other, of course that would require some internal synchronization. Kafka itself does not care about consumers, so it will not keep track itself about the latest index. You need to do the work. Another possibility would be to actually consume the messages (like, delete them from queue once consumed), so each time another consumer hits the queue it is guaranteed to receive the messages another consumer left off. Of course that would depend on your usecase, can you actually delete your messages from the queue.

Comment: I was suggesting two different groups as each consumer should consume the same messages. My understanding was, up to today, that as soon as a consumer has consumed a message, the other consumer cannot consume it, except if it belongs to a different group.

Comment: It depends on the "mode", if you chose to keep all messages in the queue for, say, one month, any consumer can read all messages. All they need to tell the queue about is an index timestamp. The queue will answer with all messages after said timestamp. Think of it as a data buffer, a consumer could actually drop all his data and re-read them from the queue. And of course a consumer can read all the topics it wants, basically kafka does not care about consumers. Or producers, for that matter ;)

Comment: Looks like it is possible to tell an "index timestamp" only using the Java Client (using offsetsForTimes) I haven't found it for Python or Scala... Is there another way ?

Comment: sorry i just realized it is as well available for the python client, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problematic treated by kafka directly (consumer group is to distribute partitions among members, not to attribute the same offset), but you can do somehting for this. You could simply create an other topic, where consumer1 would post either offset or copy of the message read (so you would need bth consumer and producer for this), and your other synchronized consumer would react against this - of course there ould be some latency for this.

What is your use case behind this? Why can't you consume at different offset? Couldn't you rather having one consumer, which would then dispatch the message read to to different processes, so that they are indeed synchronized? (with no latency)

What do you mean by synchronized: should consumer2 (and 3 and more) only consume the same message than consumer1 (ie can't consume faster, what I assume in both previous solution) While this is possible, it would really be better to know the reason behind this, maybe there is a better way for you to process data

Comment: at T1: 
- the first consumer has reached message with offset=N
- the second consumer start to consume the same topic, but start from offset=N

at next poll, both consumers shall consume the same messages

Comment: well, when they poll depend of how fast they process messages, or when they poll exactly. What do you try to achieve exactly? (why do you need exact synchro?)